# mysql problems with full text and type

Tags: php, mysql, sql, apache, mysql-error-1214

I'm using xampp software
In that I opened mysql my admin and paste that sql code. That shows an error like

`#1214 - The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes`

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE = MYISAM' at line 7`

```
CREATE TABLE code (
 id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 chapter TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 code TEXT NOT NULL,
 FULLTEXT (title,code)
) TYPE = MYISAM;
```

Comment: have you tried to `ALTER TABLE table ENGINE = MYISAM?` I do this even my default engine is already MyISAM.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
CREATE TABLE code 
( 
  id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  chapter TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
  code TEXT NOT NULL, 
  FULLTEXT (title,code) 
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. but why to use engine=myisam??